# How to use standard evaluation in dplyr for nested functions

Tags: r, dplyr

In a data frame I want to have a column with a number extracted from another column which name is only given as a variable:

```
> name <- 'x'
> df <- data.frame(x = '01abc78')
> mutate_(df, number = as.numeric(substr(name, 6, 7)))
```

But it puts 'NA' values in the new column:

```
        x number
1 01abc78     NA
```

Curiously enough

```
> mutate_(df, number = substr(name, 6, 7))
```

throws an error:

```
Error in parse(text = x)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Only

```
> mutate_(df, number = name)
```

works but does a different thing. Also get() is no solution:

```
> mutate(df, number = as.numeric(substr(get(name), 6, 7)))
Error: object 'x' not found
```

Of course I could do

```
mutate_(df, number = name) %>% mutate(number = as.numeric(substr(number, 6, 7)
```

but it sure isn't pretty.

How can I fix this to use either only mutate_ or get()?

Comment: Which version you are using?  The `mutate(df, number = substr(get(name), 6, 7))` works for me with dplyr_0.7.4

Comment: Updated to 0.7.4: Yes, now that version works. Thank you! And silly me.. I find it still strange though that the behavior of  the mutate_  version depends on the nested functions. I would intuitively think that if 'substr(number, 6, 7)' throws an error then 'as.numeric(substr(number, 6, 7))' also can't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `rlang::sym` to convert it to `symbol` and then use `!!` to get it evaluated

```
df %>%
   mutate(number = substr(!! rlang::sym(name), 6, 7))
#        x number
#1 01abc78     78
```

Answer (score 0):

Using paste can help

```
dots = paste0("as.numeric(substr(",name,", 6, 7) )")
mutate_(df, .dots = setNames(dots,"number"))
```